# how can I refresh the query inside the div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I am using JavaScript to refresh `div` content and load a PHP file containing a query to get data from MySQL.

This is my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    $('#random_notes').load('include/blocks/random_stories.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 2000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
<div id="random_notes" class='random'>s</div>
```

This is my PHP file:

```
<?php
    include "../../cp/config.php";
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM stories ORDER BY RAND()");
    $random_story = mysql_fetch_object($query);
    echo $random_story->title;
?>
```

The page loads and shows one row. The refresh does not get another row from the database. What am I missing?

Is there another good piece of code to do the same thing? This code needs cleaning cache whenever I do anything.

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Comment: Thanks for the link it will help me much coz iam still learning

Comment: try running the php script on its own, check what is displayed, you will also have to be looping through the result set

Comment: @Lappies Yeah its working and wvery refresh change the rows but i need the jquery to refresh the div automatically its refresh successfully but the php file always get the same result coz its not refreshed all i need is refreshing the php file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested your logic and it works fine for me, this is what i have

```
<div id="random_notes">
sdas
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#random_notes').load('include/blocks/random_stories.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 5000)
});
</script>
```

this should work for you

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through results in PHP

```
while( $random_story = mysql_fetch_object($query) ) {
    echo $random_story->title;
}
```

Comment: thanks you but its same thing only one row then get the same row always why the random dont work ?

Comment: its 30 rows and i it show all then i used LIMIT 1 its now show only one and dont refresh

Answer (score 0):

Ok Done i got the fix

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#random_notes").load("include/blocks/random_stories.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
     $("#random_notes").load("include/blocks/random_stories.php");
   }, 2000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>

<div id="random_notes" class='random'>s</div>
```

it was cach problems i just turn cach off everything going fine now